# "Stop talking now!" or "You must stop talking now."

Tags: modal-verbs, imperative-sentences

Which one is more commonly used (in this context) ? *Imperative form* or *must*?

> - I don't believe you, stop talking now!
> - I don't believe you, you must stop talking now.

Comment: "Commonly used" is difficult to answer because there are likely differences in regions. Personally "You must stop talking now" sounds really odd to me... then again, so does "stop talking now". I'm pretty sure most people would say "Shut up!".

Comment: I would guess that the imperative form is more commonly used, but what exactly is "the context"?  Telling someone to stop talking?  Of course we usually use the imperative form for that.  "You must X" is technically a statement, not an imperative.

Comment: "Shut up. You're lying."  "You're lying." Might be enough, to stop the person talking. It all depends on context.  "I think you are lying and am asking you to stop it/talking."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the examples of your type, wanting to get across a command / idea as quickly as possible, the imperatives would be more commonly used. It is a shorter form and can be said more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You  use simple imperative when you want to tell somebody to do something, usually because **you want them to do it**.

You use **you must** to imply that it's not (just) something that you want, and that the requirement **comes from some outside agency**.

> Stop wasting my time! - *I want you to do this*
>
> You must fill in your tax form by the end of April. - *the government wants you do do this*